# What does pentamethylarsenic smell of?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organometallic-compounds, smell

[Trimethylarsine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimethylarsine) smells of garlic. According to Wikipedia,  [pentamethylarsenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentamethylarsenic) smells like pentamethylantimony but I can't find the smell of that anywhere.

**What does pentamethylarsenic smell of?**

Comment: Well, it says it's "otherwise unique" - if that's accurate, than only the two compounds share the smell and it's different then any other.

Comment: @Mithoron I took it to mean that they only shared the smell and nothing else, i.e. was unique from pentamethylantimony in everything else.

Comment: Hmm, the cited book says: "characteristic odor which resembles the analogous antimony compound". Thing is it's not like smell is really quantifiable in a way color is. So would would you like you know? Some common smells that are somewhat similar?

Comment: @mithoron common smells would be great

Comment: Well, I didn't find anything, but "characteristic odor" probably means it stinks terribly in unusual way  ;)

Comment: Funny how “characteristic odor” is used to describe something no sane person would ever deliberately smell. So how would that rare insane person know it was characteristic and did not smell like something they had never smelled previously? In any event, “garlic” seems to be the default descriptor I have seen most often used for smelly stuff.

Comment: Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacodyl. Bunsen almost died from inadvertently getting a whiff of cacodyl cyanide. Derek Lowe writes about the episode, but I cannot locate the link offhand. But everything Lowe writes is fabulous!